# How to toggleClass inside a twig (if condition)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twig

I have a bookmark icon that I want to enable it based on a twig condition.

first of all this is the disabled with inspect:
[image: isabled]

enabled:
[image: isabled]

as you can see here all I do is to inject the class faved to the button:

```
class="faved"
```

now after we can understand each other here is the my twig test code which tested if the book is bookmarked

```
{% for favs in fav %}
  {% if livre.idLivre == favs.idLivre.idLivre %}
   <h>favorited book in the database</h>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

output

[image: output]

as you can see I can capture the the favorited books in the db and printed 'favorited book in the database' as a test

this is my full twig code that contains the btn code:

```
{% for favs in fav %}
{% if livre.idLivre == favs.idLivre.idLivre %}
<h>favorited book in the database</h>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
 <div align="center" id="{{ livre.idLivre }}">
ajouter au favoris
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"rel="stylesheet">
<button id="heart">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart">
</span>
</span>
</button>
```

now the task that I want to do is to change the status of the icon enabled or with other words inject the `class="faved"` to the button if the twig condition is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take your condition and make it inline to determine if the class should be added on the button.

Here I've created a variable to determine if the favorite exists. Then I use the inline condition to add the class to the button when faved==true.

```
{% set faved = false %}
{% for favs in fav %}
{% if livre.idLivre == favs.idLivre.idLivre %}
{% set faved = true %}
<h>favorited book in the database</h>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<div align="center" id="{{ livre.idLivre }}">
ajouter au favoris
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"rel="stylesheet">
<button id="heart" class="{{ (faved) ? 'faved' : '' }}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart">
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: WORK LIKE A CHARM